# numpy tensordot and longfloat - speed issues

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I make intensive use of numpy's tensordot for big tensors. Now, I need to increase the precision of my calculations - that's why I had to replace the 64 bit float by the 96 bit longfloat in my calculations. Unfortunately, this had a tremendous impact on the performance. While I intuitively expected a speed loss of a factor four for this new type, I had to realize that the real speed loss is of a factor 200. It seems that the BLAS library respectively the MKL (I have access to several servers) are not able to handle this type well.

Do you know a way to have fast tensor or alternatively matrix multiplication with high precision? I've looked into Cython, but my simple approaches to obtain similar performances as BLAS and MKL failed. I'm not an expert in C - so maybe there is a suitable library. But as far as I know, they all use BLAS or MKL, as well. Therefore, I expect the some speed loss.

On the other hand, if the speed loss can not be avoided, is there a Cython method which really uses 128 bit and not just 96, as the so-called "float128" of numpy does?

Comment: The problem here is that there's hardly any *hardware* that supports 96-bit floats ...  The best you can get away with is 80-bit extended precision, which has *some* hardware support on x86.

Comment: Which brings back to main question: what motivates the need for more than 64-bits?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. If you have running code to be optimized, you could go for [coderview@stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you have code not running, you should post it for the community to help you. Otherwise you question is quite broad...